# How to populate a form from an instance in model when the form is using Form instead of ModelForm?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-users

I am making a Django project where users can sign up, sign in, view their profile and change it if they want to.

I want to know how to implement the functionality of a user changing their profile?

Here is my user form in forms.py

```
class CustomerForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(label='Desired Username', max_length=150, validators=[validate_username])
    first_name  = forms.CharField(label='First Name', max_length=150)
    last_name = forms.CharField(label='Last Name', max_length=150)
    email = forms.EmailField(label='Your Email', validators=[validate_email])
    password1 = forms.CharField(label='Enter Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput, min_length=8)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Retype Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput, min_length=8)

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        password1 = cleaned_data.get("password1")
        password2 = cleaned_data.get("password2")

        if password1 != password2:
            raise ValidationError(
                "Passwords do not match"
            )
```

Here is my sign-up method in views.py

```
"""Function for sign up."""
def sign_up(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CustomerForm(request. POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            try:
                user = User.objects.create_user(
                    request.POST['username'],
                    request.POST['email'], request.POST['password1']
                )
                user.first_name = request.POST['first_name']
                user.last_name = request.POST['last_name']
                user.save()
                request.session['normal_username'] = request.POST['username']
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('../book/')
            except Exception:
                return HttpResponse("Something went wrong. Please try again.")
        else:
            context = {'form': form}
            return render(request, 'sign_up.html', context)

    context = {'form': CustomerForm()}
    return render(request, 'sign_up.html', context)
```

Edit: I cannot user [UserCreationForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/_modules/django/contrib/auth/forms/) because it is depreciated.

Edit 2: The main problem that I am facing is that I cannot populate the form using 'instance' parameter since I am using Form instead of ModelForm. Is there a way to populate the form?

```
"""Function for editing profile."""
def edit_profile(request):
    profile = User.objects.get(username=request.session['normal_username'])

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CustomerForm(request.POST, instance=profile)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('../book/')
        else:
            context = {'form': form}
            return render(request, 'sign_up.html', context)
    context = {'form': CustomerForm(instance=profile)}
    return render(request, 'edit.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use Django's included UserCreationForm, instead of trying to do it all yourself- it'll make it alot easier on yourself... Especially when it comes to connecting the form to the User Model.
Follow [this guide](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/02/18/how-to-create-user-sign-up-view.html) to make the create form (look for the *Sign Up With Extra Fields* header)

After you get the Sign-Up form done it's pretty easy to create an edit form from that base:

```py
def edituser(request):

    # instance = request.user
    # ^ Uses logged in user to pre-fill the form!

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=raw_password)
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('home')

    data = {
      'form': SignUpForm(instance=request.user)
    }
    return render(request, 'edituser.html', data)
    # edituser.html would be a copy of the signup.html template!
    #  You might even be able to use the same template as the signup, but I'm not 100% sure
```

---

### Guide's TLDR

- in case the link ever breaks

##### form.py

```py
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=False, help_text='Optional.')
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=False, help_text='Optional.')
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=254, help_text='Required. Inform a valid email address.')

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password1', 'password2', )
```

##### view.py

```py
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect

from mysite.core.forms import SignUpForm

def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=raw_password)
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = SignUpForm()
    return render(request, 'signup.html', {'form': form})
```

##### signup.html (template)

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
  <h2>Sign up</h2>
  <form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for field in form %}
      <p>
        {{ field.label_tag }}<br>
        {{ field }}
        {% if field.help_text %}
          <small style="color: grey">{{ field.help_text }}</small>
        {% endif %}
        {% for error in field.errors %}
          <p style="color: red">{{ error }}</p>
        {% endfor %}
      </p>
    {% endfor %}
    <button type="submit">Sign up</button>
  </form>
{% endblock %}
```

---

If you are deadset on **not** using a ModelForm, for some reason, I could probably whip up an example using the normal form (it would just be more complicated and a lot more work)

Comment: I cannot user UserCreationForm because it is depreciated.

Comment: The [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/default/#module-django.contrib.auth.forms) don't show them as depreciated. That link is the most recent released version but it also doesn't show depreciated in the Dev version.

Comment: Please refer to this [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/_modules/django/contrib/auth/forms/). django.contrib.auth.forms is depreciated.

Comment: That's just saying Django version 1.8 is depreciated in general, not those forms. Holy Moly we're on Django 4, you should think about upgrading

Comment: What are you saying, the solution you suggested uses UserCreationForm which I don't want to use for the reasons I stated above and I am using 4.1. That's why I want a latest answer.

Comment: [Django 4.1 on Github contrib/auth/forms.py](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/4.1.x/django/contrib/auth/forms.py) + [Django Current Dev on Github contrib/auth/forms.py](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/auth/forms.py) It ain't deprecated. It wouldn't even make sense for them to deprecate it and **not** replace it with something similar+easier. But w/e you do it the hard way idc